# Perf wrapper for Excel VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

### Spoiler

This code is **actually BAD for performances**! So **don't use it!** ;)

---

For a while now, I've been using this wrapper to avoid retyping most of it :

```
Public Sub PerfWrap(SubNameToRun As String, _
                    Optional ByVal DispStatusBar As Boolean = False, _
                    Optional ArgumentsToPass As String = vbNullString)
    Dim aWB As Workbook, _
        ActiveSH As Worksheet, _
        ScreenUpdateState As Boolean, _
        StatusBarState As Boolean, _
        CalcState As XlCalculation, _
        EventsState As Boolean, _
        DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean
    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ActiveSH = aWB.ActiveSheet
    DoEvents
    With Application
        ScreenUpdateState = .ScreenUpdating
        StatusBarState = .DisplayStatusBar
        CalcState = .Calculation
        EventsState = .EnableEvents
        DoEvents
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = DispStatusBar
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    DisplayPageBreakState = ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    If ArgumentsToPass <> vbNullString Then
        Application.Run SubNameToRun, ArgumentsToPass
    Else
        Application.Run SubNameToRun
    End If

    DoEvents
    ActiveSH.Activate
    ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks = DisplayPageBreakState
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
        .DisplayStatusBar = StatusBarState
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
        .Calculation = CalcState
        .EnableEvents = EventsState
    End With
End Sub
```

I use it like this :

```
Public Sub Launcher_CopyAndUpdate()
    Call PerfWrap("CopyAndUpdate_Templates", True)
End Sub
```

Or to pass arguments to the runned procedure :

```
Public Sub Launcher_Update()
    Call PerfWrap("Update_Templates", True, "Arg1, Arg2")
End Sub
```

---

I was wondering if :

- it can be improved regarding performances
- converted as a function to return the value sent by the runned function

Anyhow, any input or opinion is very welcome! :)

Comment: I do what Mat said: "You could even wrap that toggle behavior in a class, encapsulate the state [...] and use the Class_Terminate handler to revert back to original state, that way the calling code couldn't even "forget" to toggle it back:"

Comment: @sysmod : Do you have this visible somewhere to check it out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I'd like to echo @Mat'sMug's distaste for your multi-lined `Dim` statements.  There's absolutely no reason to do this *at all* having them prefixed with `Dim` makes it completely obvious that I'm looking at a declaration block.  It took me a good minute to realize that it wasn't a continuation of `Sub` declaration, because the `Dim` literally disappears into a huge wall of code. You aren't saving any time typing it either - last time I checked, `Dim` and `, _` were both 3 characters, and the former is a *lot* easier to type on a qwerty keyboard.

---

The other answers hint around the performance, but I'll just come right out and say it.  Your `Sub` should really be named the `AntiPerfWrap`.  First, every single call that `Application.Run` makes is late bound - ***even for Excel objects***.  It has to be, because like `CallByName`, it is forced to call `IDispactch.GetIDsOfNames` *on itself*.  This is always slower than an early bound call - period, end of discussion.

---

You always cache the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` regardless of whether it is necessary or not.  I would guess that roughly 1% of all the code I've written requires this.  Same thing with `.Calculation`.  Same thing with `.EnableEvents`.  Do I write another `PerfWrapWithEvents` if I need that turned on?  Or maybe `PerfWrapWithEventsAllowCalculation`?  None of this work is free, and it seems like a jumbled collection of "this will make your code go faster anecdotes" collected from SO comments.  The cargo cult has found thier messiah in this wrapper.

---

`DoEvents` is not free.  In fact it's the complete opposite.  It ***yields the processor*** to every other thread that needs to clear it's event queue.  It also makes absolutely no sense to call `DoEvents` when you've explicitly disabled 95% of the functionality that would make the call useful.

---

Brass tacks time - let's see how much overhead this wrapper really adds.  This is the called routine:

```
Public Sub UnderTest()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print i
    Next
End Sub
```

And the baseline benchmark:

```
Public Sub BenchmarkOne()
    Dim starting As Single
    starting = Timer

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Sheet1.UnderTest
    Next

    Debug.Print "Unwrapped: " & Timer - starting
End Sub
```

> Unwrapped: 0.8515625

```
Public Sub BenchmarkTwo()
    Dim starting As Single
    starting = Timer

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        PerfWrap "Sheet1.UnderTest"
    Next

    Debug.Print "Wrapped: " & Timer - starting
End Sub
```

> Wrapped: 6.492188

*Ouch.*

---

**Conclusion** - Burn it.  Burn it with fire.  The premise behind the code is that there is a common set of operations that you can do to "speed up" code.  In fact, this is *never* true.  In reality, you are turning off Excel functionality that can *slow down* code.  There's a big difference.  If you approach performance issues by looking outside of code that you've written, you're starting out looking in the wrong direction.  A catch-all "solution" for performance simply doesn't exist, so I wouldn't pretend to be providing it.  The best way to look at it is to imagine that any code under performance review to be copied and pasted in place of this...

> ```
> If ArgumentsToPass <> vbNullString Then
>     Application.Run SubNameToRun, ArgumentsToPass
> Else
>     Application.Run SubNameToRun
> End If
> ```

...then do a code review on the entire thing.  Ask yourself, "In the context of the full Sub, what is the reason for every single line of code other than part above"? I'm guessing that in roughly 99.99% of cases, there won't be a good answer for all of them.

Comment: **OUCH!!!** Indeed! I couldn't imagine that it was THAT BAD... I knew that it wasn't good, but in fact it is quite an horror show!^^ I didn't know that `Application.Run` was so bad, and was just looking for something easier to use for the multiples UI actions. Anyway, thx for showing me how BAD it was! I'll get rid of this right now! ;)

Comment: "The cargo cult has found thier messiah in this wrapper." I want to put this on my wall.

Answer (score 5):

You're inverting the caller/callee chain here. There are pro's and con's, but IMO more con's than pro's - `Application.Run` is a performance hit in the first place, and with the stringly-typed parameters you lose compile-time validation of your code... which I would do *anything* to try and preserve as much as possible.

Another downside is that it's not going to work on class methods, so you can't have an object that's responsible for interacting with a worksheet - may or may not be a problem, but utility code shouldn't be driving design decisions of its calling code that way.

---

This declaration is annoying:

```
Dim aWB As Workbook, _
    ActiveSH As Worksheet, _
    ScreenUpdateState As Boolean, _
    StatusBarState As Boolean, _
    CalcState As XlCalculation, _
    EventsState As Boolean, _
    DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean
```

You (or a maintainer) can't add a comment on any of those. This is probably going to break syntax highlighting in this post, but...

```
Dim aWB As Workbook, _ 'a comment here is illegal
    ActiveSH As Worksheet, _
    ScreenUpdateState As Boolean, _
    StatusBarState As Boolean, _
    CalcState As XlCalculation, _
    EventsState As Boolean, _
    DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean
```

Here's how the VBE sees it:

[image: compile error]

And if you manage to squeeze a legit comment in there, well you better hope you have `Option Explicit` specified:

```
Dim aWB As Workbook, _
    ActiveSH As Worksheet, _
    ScreenUpdateState As Boolean 'oh, and this one is legal, but... _
    StatusBarState As Boolean, _
    CalcState As XlCalculation, _
    EventsState As Boolean, _
    DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean
```

I would simply avoid cramming multiple declarations in a single statement, there's no real reason to do that... and there *are* real reasons to avoid it:

[image: Compile error: too many line continuations]

Variables should be declared close to their first use anyway, not in a wall of declarations at the top of the procedure.

FWIW with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (a COM add-in for the VBE that I [and other fellow VBA reviewers] is [are] working on), that's a one-click fix:

[image: Inspection Results > Fix > Separate multiple declarations into multiple instructions]

That instantly turns the statement into this:

> ```
> Dim aWB As Workbook
> Dim ActiveSH As Worksheet
> Dim ScreenUpdateState As Boolean
> Dim StatusBarState As Boolean
> Dim CalcState As XlCalculation
> Dim EventsState As Boolean
> Dim DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean
> ```

---

You don't need the the `aWB` local variable at all (a terrible name IMO), since you already have `ActiveSH` (which I'd probably rename to `originalActiveSheet`), and its `.Parent` member points to the originally active workbook.

---

It's not clear why `SubNameToRun` and `ArgumentsToPass` are passed `ByRef` (implicitly), when `DispStatusBar` is explicitly `ByVal` - all parameters could very well be `ByVal` here.

Actually - and given the 30 optional parameters of `Application.Run` that would look *much* uglier, but `ArgumentsToPass` would make a much friendlier API if it were a `ParamArray` parameter; that way you could keep type safety for your arguments, which means you could pass arguments that can't be implicitly or explicitly converted to a `String` - e.g. a `Range` object.

Not being able to pass an object parameter is a serious showstopper limitation IMO.

---

I think it's a nice idea, but it's way too limited. A more flexible solution would be a simple `ToggleWaitMode` procedure that toggles `ScreenUpdating`, `DisplayStatusBar`, `Calculation`, `EnableEvents`, allows specifying an optional `StatusBar` message, and heck, that toggles the `Cursor` to/from `xlWait` as well.

You could even wrap that toggle behavior in a class, encapsulate the state (although that's a *leaky abstraction*, these things are all global really), and use the `Class_Terminate` handler to revert back to original state, that way the calling code couldn't even "forget" to toggle it back:

```
With WaitWorker.Init(statusText:="Please wait...", disableEvents:=True)

    'do stuff

End With
```

That way you don't need to do `Application.Run`, so it works with class module callers, and you're not passing a stringly-typed list of parameters either, so the caller can still do everything it wants: you're not *interfering* with the caller.

Comment: you is working on Rubberduck?

Comment: @Vogel612 yes, I is =)

Comment: Thx for the valuable inputs! I didn't though of the object parameters when I wrote the base that I reused more recently for this one (as I only use this on main program called by buttons), but indeed it is a deal-breaker for more general use (and `ParamArray` is a pretty common coding method across languages) ! `ToggleWaitMode` procedure could be interesting with a few Public variables, but I'm pretty intrigued by the class approach, and wondering **what do you mean by "leaky abstraction"**?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Out of curiosity, why should declarations be close to their use? I always thought it was opposite, but that may just be personal preference. I tend to declare whatever is easiest to use at the beginning, and then refactor for performance at the end. To this end, declaring them in a block at the top makes it much easier for me to see if I have gotten out of control and if I need to refactor.

Comment: @BrandonBarney take it to the extreme: an ugly 2000-liner procedure that has every variable declared right next to where it's used, vs the same ugly 2000-liner procedure that has every variable declared in, oh, a 2-screensfull wall of declarations at the top. With the latter (which I've worked with) you constantly find yourself scrolling up and down the procedure and lose where you were at, and waste considerable time doing just that, not to mention it's impossible to tell at a glance which variables are used and which are just dead code, at least without Rubberduck telling you.

Comment: @Mat'sMug taken to the extreme it makes perfect sense. Thankfully, I havent run into that issue before. I will admit that there are times where I have to scroll up repeatedly, but usually because I forgot to declare something. In the case of a 2000 line routine though, couldnt an argument be made for refactoring the routine into multiple subroutines? I am somewhat of a novice, but I would think that it would make the code somewhat easier to follow in some cases, and it would also potentially help with variable management. I could be dead wrong on this of course.

Comment: Oh, absolutely!! ...except if your boss is non-technical and the app is business-critical and you're just not authorized to check in non-functional changes that "don't bring any business value or fix any actual problem" =)

Comment: That said in other languages, a declaration is often an executable statement, so *where it's at* is of prime importance; in VBA/VB6, `Dim` isn't executable, so *where it's at* makes no difference as far as variable lifetime is concerned - so it's just a readability/maintainability thing.

Comment: @R3uK I mean you can wrap a global all you want, at the end of the day any code can use that global and bypass your wrapper ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm uncertain of the efficiencies in a single wrapper like this. In developing applications with multiple modules and classes, I'm often needing to disable screen updates and such but without extremely careful planning I used to always step on my own toes. So I developed two routines that allow me to disable and enable Excel application level updates and give me enough tracking debug.

Using the calls becomes as easy as sprinkling these calls around:

```
Sub SomeImportantWork()
    DisableUpdates
    '--- do stuff
    OtherImportantWork
    EnableUpdates
End Sub

Sub OtherImportantWork()
    DisableUpdates debugMsg:="enter OtherImportantWork"
    '--- work more stuff
    EnableUpdates debugMsg:="leave OtherImportantWork"
End Sub
```

My idea has been to not worry about whether I've call disable/enable, but only to make sure those calls are paired around any code that requires that protection.

At the module level, I define a structure and a private variable to hold any previous state information:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type SavedState
    screenUpdate As Boolean
    calculationType As XlCalculation
    eventsFlag As Boolean
    callCounter As Long
End Type
Private previousState As SavedState
Private Const DEBUG_MODE = True
```

Then when I want to disable application updates, I call:

```
Public Sub DisableUpdates(Optional debugMsg As String = "", _
                          Optional forceZero As Boolean = False)
    With Application
        '--- capture previous state if this is the first time
        If forceZero Or (previousState.callCounter = 0) Then
            previousState.screenUpdate = .ScreenUpdating
            previousState.calculationType = .Calculation
            previousState.eventsFlag = .EnableEvents
            previousState.callCounter = 0
        End If

        '--- now turn it all off and count
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        previousState.callCounter = previousState.callCounter + 1

        '--- optional stuff
        If DEBUG_MODE Then
            Debug.Print "Updates disabled (" & previousState.callCounter & ")";
            If Len(debugMsg) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print debugMsg
            Else
                Debug.Print vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And the mirroring method to re-enable is:

```
Public Sub EnableUpdates(Optional debugMsg As String = "", _
                         Optional forceZero As Boolean = False)
    With Application
        '--- countdown!
        If previousState.callCounter >= 1 Then
            previousState.callCounter = previousState.callCounter - 1
        Else
            '--- shouldn't get here
            Debug.Print "EnableUpdates ERROR: reached callCounter = 0"
        End If

        '--- only re-enable updates if the counter gets to zero
        '    or we're forcing it
        If forceZero Or (previousState.callCounter = 0) Then
            .ScreenUpdating = previousState.screenUpdate
            .Calculation = previousState.calculationType
            .EnableEvents = previousState.eventsFlag
        End If

        '--- optional stuff
        If DEBUG_MODE Then
            Debug.Print "Updates enabled (" & previousState.callCounter & ")";
            If Len(debugMsg) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print debugMsg
            Else
                Debug.Print vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, I have a private module flag to turn on debug messages (`DEBUG_MODE`) if I need them and turn them off for production. You can turn this into a compiler directive flag if you feel you need a (small) runtime performance boost.

The `callCounter` lets me keep track of my "updates call stack". This is especially usedful when I started calling some library routines I had and those calls got rather deep. It certainly helped to track it down.'

Also, I can go into the `Immediate` window at any time and type `EnableUpdates(forceZero=True)` and get back to a known state manually.

Comment: Thx for your input, that what I thought about when reading the other answers. I like your `DEBUG_MODE` which could be pretty handy indeed!